# How can i recognize a disconnected Client in GWT?

Tags: session, gwt

In our project our server must know as quickly as possible if a client gets disconnected.

Is there a effective way to implement this? Maybe with the `GWTEventService` or a powerfull framework?

Comment: What "client" are you talking about?

Comment: @BrianRoach i talk about a browser. How can the server recognize, if the browsertab is closed (without a logout from a user) i want to implement a chat. If the tab closed, the server must kick out the usersession from the chatlist. I know about polling, but its very ugly..(so the client send for example every 30seconds a "keep-alive" to the server)

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/ - comet is pretty much the defacto standard for implementing what you're talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- You can check out Comet. Comet was designed for this kind of behavior, where you intend to push data to the client without the client explicitly requesting it. Check out [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) about Comet for more information. There's a GWT implementation of it here: [gwt-comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/).
- Alternatives: You could use something like [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) to keep tabs on your clients. You could also implement a heartbeat-style approach, where you force the client to hit a given page every X seconds so you know they're still connected.

Honestly, there are countless ways to do what you're looking for here. I'd say Comet would be your best bet if you don't mind implementing a whole framework.

Comment: Thank you, i experiment a little bit with Comet. But for other functions in this Project i use GWTEventService...so i have the problem to decide for on this (Comet or GWTEventService)